# How to open instant apps without enabling it on google play settings?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I want to publish a link (maybe throug QR code) to enable users access my app without needing enable Instant apps from google play setting. Common user known nothing about intant app settings so that step ruins my instant apps adoption!

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en link says "Even when this setting is turned off, you can always continue to try instant apps by clicking on links that are Google Play branded." So I suponse there is a chance to do what I need but don't undestand what is a 'Google Play branded link' or how it sees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Android Instant App URL](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#UriSummary), you need to add a link with the url: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name&launch=true.  This will launch your Instant App.

Currently, if any user links through any Instant App URL for their very first time, it will prompt them to enable it. So the majority of your cases will be here.

However, once the settings have been touched, then manually turned off, then that prompt will no longer appear and Instant Apps will be fully disabled, including Try Nows. The user must manually go back to the settings to re-enable it to see it again.

The other scenario is if during that first-time prompt or IA’s speedbump screen for your app, should the user select to view the URL in the browser and not the app, then your instant app will specifically disabled, while others can still launch. At which point, again, the user will have to manually go back to the settings to manually undo your IA’s now default.

Comment: Thanks Edward but your solution is not working for me. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buzzfeed.android&launch=true sends me to play store on setting turned off.

Comment: Sorry but not working here, even by clicking link from a mail on gmail. Are you sure you got no instant app setting turned on?

Comment: Is it possible to pass a parameter to the instant app using this method?

Comment: @Bennik2000 could you pass a param to the instant app?

Comment: Is there any news on this subject ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the linking to the PlayStore guide there is no way to launch the Instant App if the Instant App feature is not enabled on the users device: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#Instant